# python convert one json structure to a nested structure

Tags: python, json, converters

how can I convert the following json format to the target format below? I have 50 thousand entries.
Basically, get the unique country from each array and include all other with the same country name under one array.

original json:

```
[
    {
        "unilist": [
                {
                    "country": "United States",
                    "name": "The College of New Jersey",
                    "web_page": "http://www.tcnj.edu"
                },
                {
                    "country": "United States",
                    "name": "Abilene Christian University",
                    "web_page": "http://www.acu.edu/"
                },
                {
                    "country": "United States",
                    "name": "Adelphi University",
                    "web_page": "http://www.adelphi.edu/"
                },
                {
                    "country": "China",
                    "name": "Harbin Medical University",
                    "web_page": "http://www.hrbmu.edu.cn/"
                },
                {
                    "country": "China",
                    "name": "Harbin Normal University",
                    "web_page": "http://www.hrbnu.edu.cn/"
                }
                ...
                ]
    }
]
```

target format:

```
{
"unilist" : {
        "United States" : [
          {"name" : "The College of New Jersey", "web_page" : "http://www.tcnj.edu"},
          {"name" : "Abilene Christian University", "web_page" : "http://www.acu.edu/"},
          {"name" : "Adelphi University", "web_page" : "http://www.adelphi.edu/"}
        ],
        "China" : [
          {"name" : "Harbin Medical University", "web_page" : "http://www.hrbnu.edu.cn/"}
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

### update

my attempt (in Python 2.7.11) based on the [answer provided by downshift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40494910/4835480), however it is not working as expected, I get the following typeError:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('old_list.json') as orig_json:    
    newlist = defaultdict(list)

for country in orig_json[0]['unilist']:
    newlist[country['country']].append({'name': country['name'], 'web_page': country['web_page']})

with open('new_list.json', 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(newlist,fp)


pprint.pprint(dict(newlist))
```

TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 8, in <module>
    for country in orig_json[0]['unilist']:
TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces *almost* the same target output, only it's missing the `"unilist"` key. But at least it does group entries by country:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

with open('original.json', 'r') as original:
    orig_json = original.read()[1:-1] # Remove outermost list brackets([]) to enable parsing data as JSON data, not a list

oj = json.loads(orig_json)

newlist = defaultdict(list)

for country in oj['unilist']:
    newlist[country['country']].append({'name': country['name'], 
                                        'web_page': country['web_page']})

with open('new.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(newlist, outfile)
```

This will save the `newlist` to a json file 'newlist.json'

Output:

```
{'China': [{'name': 'Harbin Medical University',
            'web_page': 'http://www.hrbmu.edu.cn/'},
           {'name': 'Harbin Normal University',
            'web_page': 'http://www.hrbnu.edu.cn/'}],
 'United States': [{'name': 'The College of New Jersey',
                    'web_page': 'http://www.tcnj.edu'},
                   {'name': 'Abilene Christian University',
                    'web_page': 'http://www.acu.edu/'},
                   {'name': 'Adelphi University',
                    'web_page': 'http://www.adelphi.edu/'}]}
```

I'll update this answer if I get figure out a better way to get the exact target output. In the meantime, I hope this helps you.

Comment: ok thanks, i am going to test this and let you know what the result is.

Comment: how do I open define my file entry , how to define `defaultdict`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have included that module import: `from collections import defaultdict`. added to edit

Comment: sorry i am a newbie here, could you help me to define and read my file into the code and then save it as another output file?

Comment: i updated my question based on your answer, could you please look at the error the code is throwing. why is it happening?

Comment: Sure. I'll add that to my answer. by the way thanks for accepting.